# get nearest value of second element in list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to get the list that has the values closest to the value i compare it with

Example list

```
[('MK20G / MK20H', 7.1, 7.1, 31, 10), ('MK10G / MK10H', 9.3, 9.3, 18.5, 10)]
```

And compare value

```
1.34
```

Result should be

```
('MK20G / MK20H', 7.1, 7.1, 31, 10)
```

since element 1 and 2 are closest to 1.34

but when i have a value of 7.5 it should select ('MK10G / MK10H', 9.3, 9.3, 18.5, 10)

So >= should be used

I tried

```
nearest = min(value10, key=lambda x: (x, D))
```

but it does not seems to work.
value10 holds mt tuple and D is the value to compare with (1.34 in this example)

If possible it would be nice to get the highest value of element 1 and 2 before selecting
I know in my example list the values are equal but it can happen that the 2 values are not the same and then the highest of the 2 are needed

Comment: What are the bounds for the value (1.34 in your example)?

Comment: For what it's worth, [here is a solution](https://gist.github.com/kalatabe/6ebf071fde6ee8be47a8829346993371) that should work with most values of D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when i have a value of 7.5 it should select ('MK10G / MK10H', 9.3, 9.3, 18.5, 10)
>
> So >= should be used

This basically mean you want the lowest value of values higher than `D`.

Let's say `my_list` holds the list of all tuples.

```
my_list = [('MK20G / MK20H', 7.1, 7.1, 31, 10), ('MK10G / MK10H', 9.3, 9.3, 18.5, 10)]
D = 1.7
nearest = min([elem for elem in my_list if elem[1] >= D], key=lambda x: x[1])
```